# Probability in poisson's distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Car crashes within one week can be modeled with random variable X which follows distribution:
where $\lambda = 0.7$
$$P(X=k)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$
**(a)** What is probability that within in next week there will be at least 2 car crashes.

**(b)** What is probability that during next 3 weeks wont have any car crashes, if we assume that each weeks amount of car crashes doesn't depend on other weeks.

**(c)** How many car crashes can be expected within one week

**(d)** How many car crashes can be expected within 3 weeks ?

**Hint**: Formula $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ could be useful.

Comment: Of course, $P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ and there is no PDF.

Comment: This isn't an exponential distribution, it's a Poisson distribution (once corrected for the $\lambda^k/k!$ not being inside the exponential). The Poisson distribution and exponential distribution are related, in the sense that if $X_i$ are independent, identically distributed exponential random variables then $Y_t=\min \left \{ n : \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq t \right \}$ is a Poisson variable for each fixed $t>0$. The $X_i$ are the "waiting times" between "events", while $Y_t$ is the number of "events" that have occurred up to time $t$. Perhaps this relationship is the origin of your confusion.

Comment: It is corrected to $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ now

Comment: I made a mistake, I should have max in my previous comment, not min. Also $0$ is always in that set, by the convention for the empty sum.

Comment: Too broad.  Too many questions asked in one post.

Comment: I figured them all out and i will be posting answers soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i figured out correct answers to these questions. **Note that this not might be the most optimal way to solve these.** Please provide more optimal solution if you can think of one.

**(a)** What is probability that within in next week there will be at least 2 car crashes.

> #### Solution (a):
>
> We can get correct answer by summing probabilities with discrete random variable values.
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{11}e^{-0.7}\frac{0.7^k}{k!}≈1$$
>   I got this by trial and error. Finding sum large enough to be approximately $≈1$. Now we can assume that we have all probabilities in this range(0-11). Now we want to know probability for $P(X\ge2)$
>   $$P(X\ge2)=\sum_{k=2}^{11}e^{-0.7}\frac{0.7^k}{k!}≈0.1558049835$$

---

**(b)** What is probability that during next 3 weeks wont have any car crashes, if we assume that each weeks amount of car crashes doesn't depend on other weeks.

> #### Solution (b):
>
> We can get probability for zero car crashes within one week by:
>   $$P(X=0)=e^{-0.7}\frac{0.7^0}{0!}≈0.4965853038$$
>   Since each week is independent of each other we can simply probability of $(P(X=0))^3$
>   $$(P(X=0))^3=(e^{-0.7}\frac{0.7^0}{0!})^3≈0.1224564283$$

---

**(c)** How many car crashes can be expected within one week

> #### Solution (c):
>
> In Poisson distribution $E(X)=\lambda$ is true (Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution))
>   $$E(X)=0.7$$

**(d)** How many car crashes can be expected within 3 weeks ?

> #### Solution (d):
>
> This is same as **solution (b)** but multiplying it 3 times.
>   $$E(X)*3=2.1$$